# How do you create a two-column Word document where each column is a different file?

Tags: ms-word, ms-office

Is it possible to create a two-column Word document, where each column shows a different file?

I would like to print out a text in different languages, original and translation, side by side to learn a foreign language, but I cannot figure out how to do it.

Comment: SO isn't the place for discussing how to use MS Office applications.

Comment: Unless the OP is talking about Office automation, but unfortunately this was not specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a table with two columns, paste one document in the left column, the other in the right.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to automate something in Word, one technique is to use Word's macro recorder to record yourself doing the same task (or a similar one). That results in VBA code that's pretty close to what you need. Take that code and adapt it for use in your program.

Comment: I don't know how to do it manually. I don't need to automate it

Comment: Then this was not the proper venue for your question.